# Codename one error sending release build to itunesconnect with iphone_new

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, codenameone, cfbundleidentifier

When I send my ipa file to itunes connect using Application Loader after sending and downloading an IOS release build using the Target 'iphone_new' in my build.xml for release and debug I get an error message: "info.plist contains an invalid key CFBundleResourceSpecification” and the build fails to send. I do not have this key in my ios.plistInject build hint.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in the plist and is a part of xcodes signing process, we have a fix for this that we'll deploy tomorrow.